# HTML within a div takes parent HTML's CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML as following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a {color: red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <a href="#">Test Link</a>
                </body>
            </html>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

"Test Link" is displayed in green color. By this I understand that the HTML inside div takes parent HTML's CSS. In my scenario, I do not have control over the parent HTML. I can only control div's contents. Is there a way to have a clean, fresh CSS for the HTML inside div? I dont want the parent HTML's CSS to be applied to the HTML inside div. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is disgusting, use an iframe instead.

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a {color: red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unrelated, I'm so sorry, but you're colourblind.

Comment: Haha, sh*t! You're right.. Didn't even realize he said green instead of red. Not sure if troll ;)

Comment: Its just that I get to modify only div's content. It actually is not "my html" :) Thanks for the idea. iFrames work!!

Comment: So sorry about the color confusion . . thanks for solving my problem!

Comment: Than invalid HTML? I think not! Like all things, iframes have their uses, in particular displaying content from another web page, which is exactly what user443161 is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `>` child selector.

```
body>a {
  color: red;
}
```

This will only style links that are direct children of the body. Bear in mind, IE doesn't support this.

And may I suggest use proper syntax

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body>a {color: red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
           <a href="#">Test Link</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's called css as in _cascading_ style sheet. That means, that a parent's style definition _cascades_ down to its descendants. So your 'problem' is actually the way css is meant to work. Also, read a css tutorial or 10. http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to use the HTML tag like that. It doesn't restart CSS properties.

If you don't want all a tags to be green, don't use CSS to say you do!

Answer (score 0):

Man, you code is terrible and invalid :) To have a clean, fresh CSS for the HTML inside div you may use iframe.

Comment: Bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: Bit harder way is use "class" tag in every element. E.g. <a class="outside">1</a> and <a class="inside">2</a>.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *localised reset*.

Grab a CSS reset, e.g. [Eric Meyer's Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) and change it to apply to your div.

So, in front of every element, put your `div`'s `id` or something there. Feel free to trim the huge list of selectors to what you use. If this `div` is being included into other people's pages, you may want to faux namespace it (and children with `id` or `class`) like `my-element-container`. This will ensure no naming clashes. You can use CSS namespacing when it is widely supported (a while off still...)

Then you can play with CSS inside.

**Also**, validate your HTML. Look at the errors, and fix them. Don't rely on your browser's error handling of markup, as it just makes things a pain to debug.